# Jquery .html refreshes dom but sometimes doesn't show on screen?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a textbox on a form whose contents are set by a jquery function. I use the same function for multiple textboxes. In some instances it works perfectly though seems that on the first one it updates the DOM so when I inspect it I can see the contents of the textbox has changed, though on screen it shows as blank?

so the first instance looks like:

```
<div class='form-group director1'>
   <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Company Address</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6"><textarea id="a1-companyaddress" class='form-control' name="a1-companyaddress" rows="5" cols="40" style="overflow-y: scroll;">&nbsp;</textarea></div>                              
</div>
```

and the second looks like:

```
<div class='form-group director2'>
  <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Company Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><textarea id='a2-companyaddress' class='form-control' name='a2-companyaddress' rows="5" cols="40" style="overflow-y: scroll;"></textarea></div>                             
</div>
```

the code triggering the update is a on a button as follows:

```js
$('.companysearch').click(function() {
  $('#loading').show();
  var prefix = $(this).attr('title');
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'chouseapi.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      typ: 'fetchcompanydetails',
      company: $('#' + prefix + '-companynumber').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var bits = data.split('~');
      var cno = $('#' + prefix + '-companynumber').val();
      $('#' + prefix + '-resetsearch').hide();
      $('#' + prefix + '-companyname').val('').show();
      $('#' + prefix + '-companynumberselect').hide();
      $('#' + prefix + '-companysearchbyname').show();

      $('#' + prefix + '-companyname').val(bits[0]);
      $('#' + prefix + '-companyincorporation').val(bits[1]);
      $('#' + prefix + '-companyaddress').html(bits[2]);
      $('#' + prefix + '-companysic').val(bits[3]);
      $('#' + prefix + '-companynumber').val(bits[4]);
      $('#' + prefix + '-companydata').html(bits[5]);
      $('#loading').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

for the a1 prefix all the inputs change apart from the textbox, for the a2 prefix it's perfectly fine. The field ids are unique on the page. why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove `async: false` from the settings of your AJAX call. It is incredibly bad practice. If you inspect the console you'll even see the browser itself telling you not to do it.

With regard to your issue, you should use `val()` to update the value of the `textarea`, not `html()`:

```
$('#' + prefix + '-companyaddress').text(bits[2]);
```

I would also strongly suggest you look in to using DOM traversal techniques. That way you can omit the unnecessary incremental `id` attributes in the HTML and get rid of the ugly `'#' + prefix + '-X'` concatenation in your JS

Comment: Thanks, the async was put in to test as somewhere else it was mentioned though have since removed.

Using .val does work though I'm trying to return rich data with newlines etc and doesn't seem to work with .val though should work with .html?